# Liquibase SQL to XML generator

Tags: liquibase

We are planning to migrate from Flyway to Liquibase.
Although Liquibase provides an option "generateChangeLog" that will output the xml changelog needed to create the database.

However we are looking to convert each of our script individually to xml , i.e each versioned script of flyway will become a versioned change set.

If done manually, it is going to be a tedious process, So we are looking forward to some automated solution for the same.

Comment: is it important to keep the history of your changes in flyway ? (if not you can use diffChangeLog)

Comment: Hi Eric, yes due to some business needs, it is imperative that we retain all the historical information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to migrate from flyway to liquibase but you can keep on one side flyway history in your souce files and begin with a diffChangeLog to initialize your liquibase from production environnement.

This way you have old history in your flyway scripts nd new history in liquibase